# putting a flag for "grandfathered but now off topic questions" like SO does

Tags: discussion

I see several questions about DNS that are upvoted and have accepted and upvoted answers. Examples:
1) [Is it possible to get a listing of all DNS records that have a given CNAME?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2111/is-it-possible-to-get-a-listing-of-all-dns-records-that-have-a-given-cname?rq=1)
2) [Why do some AAAA records behave strangely on existing A records?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21018/why-do-some-aaaa-records-behave-strangely-on-existing-a-records?rq=1)
3) [What exactly is a domain in context of DNS?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/what-exactly-is-a-domain-in-context-of-dns?rq=1)

The latest of which was in November 2015.

Yet I asked a question that was closed due to off topic: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34664/dns-record-for-a-service-at-path-after-port

In the comments, it was revealed that DNS is "now" off topic and that these were "grandfathered in". But unless you tell new users that with a breadcrumb, you are going to have this problem recurring.

Stack overflow seems to have solved this. For "grandfathered" types of questions, they add a giant warning:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed.

e.g.,: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature.

You should consider bringing such a tag to this site because as a new user it was frustrating reading several DNS questions, making my own, only to having it immediately closed.

Comment: I don't see any tag on the example? Anyway, I'm really not against this, but it's explained quite clearly in the help center what's on topic and what not.

Comment: @TeunVink there is a giant locked flag on the function... and it's not clear when you have upvoted non-closed questions that are "off topic".

Comment: Ok, you were talking about tags, I was looking at that, not at the lock itself. I think it's not really doable to re-check all old questions every time policy changes to be honest, that's why there's an explanation what's on topic.